# Get current screen brightness level

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell, laptop, brightness, color-management

The brightness keys on my laptop work ok, and gnome shell displays a level bar when changing it.

But the level bar doesn't display any values (absolute nor relative).

How can I retrieve the current brightness value?

Say - e.g. for scripting purposes - to be able to restore it later, in a reliable fashion.

Use case: for example, you created a color profile at a certain brightness level - and after temporarily changing it around you want to go back to this well-defined fixed point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that via *GNOME Settings Daemon* which is responsible for configuring the screen brightness (and many other session-wide parameters). To access the brightness settings you'll have to use the corresponding *gsd helper*:  `gsd-backlight-helper` (use `--help` to see all options).

---

To get the current brightness level, run:

```
/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-backlight-helper --get-brightness
```

Comment: This works. On Fedora 23, it is `/usr/libexec/gsd-backlight-helper`, btw.

Comment: @don_crissti After plugging my Ubuntu notebook out of the wall, the screen backlight dims to about a half, but `gsd-backlight-helper` still reports the highest value. Would you know anything about it, please?

Comment: @LogicStuff - I can't replicate that behaviour (archlinux+gnome 3.20.2); `gsd-backlight-helper` always reports the correct values so most likely there's something wrong on your side.